# count_chars in PHP where the number of characters is greater than 16

Tags: php, string, counting

So for some reason when I use `count_chars(11111111111111111111,3)` I get back something to the effect of `.1111111111111119`

Is there a different way to count the occurences of each character in a string?

Here's some example code

```
            $value = 11111111111111111111; 
            $value = strval($value);
            $count = count_chars($value,3);
            print_r($count);
```

If I print out the result I get +.012E

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `strval()` instead of just putting the number between quotes?

Comment: Yes I'm using strval because in the production code, the string comes in from another method and is not always of type string. Sometimes its type INT or double.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count characters in **string**, give a **string**...

```
count_chars('11111111111111111111',3)
```

ps: and if you really want to count characters use mode 1

```
 $res = count_chars('1111111111111111111122333', 1);

 foreach ($res as $char => $number) {
  echo chr($char). ' ' . $number .'<br />';
 }
```

Comment: Same thing happens regardless of if I give it a string or an INT.

Comment: For me works perfectly. Show me please your **exactly** code

Comment: You still have a big number which is too big. Can you show us how you get this numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, is that you're not using integers, but floating points.
And with floats that big, they will be shown in the scientific way (with the E).

So `11111111111111111111` becomes `1.1111111111111E+19` (in math this is the same number).
If you convert it to a string (cast, of `strval()`), it will take the second one here.
And because you will have `1.1111111111111E+19` as a string, you will get the output you give us.

Solution to this? You have a few, but they're not that good.
Best way I can think of, is using the [number_format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```
$value = number_format($value, 0, '', '');
```

Instead if the `strval()` function.

The big problem here is, is that floating points are not precisly enough for this. You will get rounding problems. See more information [here](https://secure.php.net/float).

On my computer the string would become `11111111111111110656` because it rounds to `1111111111111111.0656`.

If you know the length of the integer (16 in this case), you could use `substr()` for this, but again: it will only be a workaround.